# Conveting Chart in Excel sheet into PDF

Tags: excel, pdf, charts

Am trying to **convert to a Chart which is available in the Excel sheet into PDF format**. I have tried this using Apache POI, JFreeChart. But am not able to do so. Am able to create a new chart in the PDF format. Help me with this Chart to PDF conversion or at least guide me to read all the available properties of the Chart.

Comment: have you tried [this](http://cschleiden.wordpress.com/2009/09/28/howto-export-excel-charts-as-pdf-to-include-in-latex-document/)?

Answer (score 0):

1. Install [PDF creator](http://www.pdfforge.org/pdfcreator)
2. [Print the chart](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/print-a-chart-HP001233755.aspx)
3. Select **PDF Creator** as the printer.
4. Voilà